# C++ changing order of vector using iter_swap

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm passing in a vector with 20 items to the function below. My aim is to change the order of the items in the vector. If the list contains the items 1 2 3 4, I want the end result to be 4 3 2 1. Basically switching the first item with the last, and the second item with the second to last item.

```
template<typename T>
void changePosition(std::vector<T>& list)
{
    std::cout << "Swapping \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        std::iter_swap(list.begin() + i, list.end() - i);
    }

    std::cout << "Swapped \n";
}
```

I just end up getting the error:

> c++ vector iterator not dereferencable

Any ideas? I haven't found any samples that achieve what I'm trying to achieve.

std::reverse could indeed be used, the assignment I'm working on requires me to use iter_swap.

Comment: You don't want to swap the iterators, you want to stop references to the elements the iterators represent. As in, `*it`. Then again, you don't need to write this yourself, check out @Soren's answer.

Comment: Just for more information, when `i==0`, `list.end() - i` just equates to `list.end()`, which isn't a valid element you can swap with. Furthermore, if you're iterating until `list.size()`, you'll end up reversing the vector twice; by the end of the loop, you'd find that you hadn't achieved anything!

Comment: @MohamadAliBaydoun Always refer to the documentation: `std::iter_swap()` swaps the items being referenced by the iterators, not the iterator itself.

Comment: @frslm You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I should've! But it looks like someone else has already done that

Comment: @MohamadAliBaydoun That's exactly what `std::iter_swap` does. `std::iter_swap(a, b);` is the same as `using std::swap; swap(*a, *b);`.

Comment: @cdhowie My bad! I didn't read `iter_swap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.end()` points one past the last element of the vector. So on the first iteration of your loop, `list.end() - i` will point one past the end, and cannot be dereferenced (or passed to `iter_swap`).

You should use `list.end() - i - 1` instead so that it starts at the last element.

But once you fix this, you will run into another problem: Your code swaps each element twice, so nothing will change. You should stop at the middle of the vector to fix this.

Of course, the best way to reverse a vector is to use the standard function `std::reverse` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I understand. It's a school assignment I'm working one that requires me to use iter_swap.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should just use [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue with the following:

```
template<typename T>
void changePosition(std::vector<T>& list)
{
    std::cout << "Swapping \n";
    typedef std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
    iterator first = list.begin();
    iterator last = list.end();

    while ((first != last) && (first != --last))
    {
        std::iter_swap(first, last);
        ++first;
    }

    std::cout << "Swapped \n";
}
```

I doubt this is the best way to go about things but it got the job done. std::reverse should indeed be used by others trying to reverse a vector.

The only reason I resort to iter_swap is because of the assignment I'm working on requiring it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iter_swap . In fact std::reverse also uses iter_swap

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

template<class BidirIt>
void reverseVector(BidirIt first, BidirIt last)
{
    while ((first != last) && (first != --last)) {
        std::iter_swap(first++, last);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4};
    for(auto v:vec)
    {
        std::cout<<v<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"After reverting"<<"\n";
    reverseVector(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    for(auto v:vec)
    {
        std::cout<<v<<" ";
    }

}
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 After reverting
4 3 2 1 Program ended with exit code: 0
```